# Can i get the value of my Key inside my react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way i can access my `key` inside my `react component` ?

```
   <LessonsLearnedNew
        key={item.id ?item.id[0]:item.tempID}

   />

  class LessonsLearnedNew extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
      console.log(props.key)  // coming as undefined
    }
  }
```

i found a work around like this. Is there a better way ?

```
<LessonsLearnedNew
            key={item.id ?item.id[0]:item.tempID}
            keyVal={item.id ?item.id[0]:item.tempID}

       />

      class LessonsLearnedNew extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
          console.log(props.key)  // coming as undefined
          console.log(props.keyVal)  // getting the value
        }
      }
```

Comment: And first check weather you are getting that as a props in the console.log(props).

Answer (score 2):

Keys are not passed to the components.
From the [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings):

> Keys serve as a hint to React but they don’t get passed to your components. If you need the same value in your component, pass it explicitly as a prop with a different name:

```
const content = posts.map((post) =>
  <Post
    key={post.id}
    id={post.id}
    title={post.title} />
);
```

So your "workaround" is actually the suggested pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`Key` is a unique identity to react. So if u have got any value to another component pass that value using `props` and the key is always so unique.

```
 <LessonsLearnedNew
    key={item.id ?item.id[0]:item.tempID} //unique identity
    keyVal={item.id ?item.id[0]:item.tempID} // pass value as a props
  />
```